# SpriteKit game laggy right after presenting

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, preload

My game is a bit laggy at first (right when I have presented the `myScene` from my `menuScene`). It 's very quick at actually loading the scene and presenting it, but if you start to play right away it's lagging.

This can be avoided by just not playing for like a second or so right away when it's loaded, but I don't want my final product to be like this. Is there a way of preloading a scene, so I actually don't present it before it's done loading?

I tried doing this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    _myScene = [[MyScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size andLevel:_currentLevel];
    _myScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    _isLoadingFinished = YES;
});
```

And then presenting the scene from my `update-loop` when the `isLoadingFinished` is set, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any advice?

Comment: are you using simulator or running it on the actual device?

Comment: @CjCoax Actual device

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but try preloading all textures https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTexture_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKTexture/preloadTextures:withCompletionHandler:

Comment: @Roecrew thanks for your reply, but I don't think it'll make a difference. I'm already using textures from all the atlases in the `menuScene`, so they should already be loaded into memory. I'll try it just to be sure though, and I'll let you know ;)